# How to check the same dataframe row containing the same phrase in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if there was a way to check each row in a DataFrame for the same word or phrase.
For example, if I a row that has values "python" repeated twice like "python python" is there a way to check this. I want to check all repeat values, so using an if regexmatch won't be viable given the large data set.

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and provide a sample input, expected output, and your attempt. That would help others to answer your question.

Comment: can you please post a sample df and it's expected output

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Pandas so I added the [tag:pandas] tag. If not, you can [edit] to change it.